# Error when upload file to ipfs in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ipfs

I trying to upload image to ipfs in react js UI. when add image using add button its work but when click on submit button get  the next error
"**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected input: null   normalise-candidate-single.js:16** " and then to store return hash from ipfs in hypeledger fabric

who can help me?

**My App.js file as follow**
**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'

const ipfs = create('http://localhost:5001') 


class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      buffer: null
    }
  }
 
  
 captureFile = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault()
   //process file for IPFS...
   const file = event.target.files[0]
   const reader = new window.FileReader()
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
   reader.onloaded = () => {
     this.setState(('buffer', Buffer(reader.result)))
   }

 }
 onSubmit = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault()
   console.log("submiting the form....")
   ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (error, result) => {
    console.log('Ipfs result', result)
    if(error) {
      console.error(error)
      return
    }
 })
}
 

  
      
      render() {
        return (
                                    
         
      <div>
        
        <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
          <div className="row">
            <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 d-flex text-center">
              <div className="content mr-auto ml-auto">
                 
                <h2>Change Logo</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                  <input type='file' onChange={this.captureFile} />
                  <input type='submit'/>
                </form>
              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
              
 export default App;
```

**

Comment: Did the error get printed by the `console.error(error)` statement within `onSubmit` function?

Comment: Your call to `ipfs.add(file, [options])` is different from the [core API](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#ipfsadddata-options), where the second argument shouldn't be a callback function. See also this [example](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#example).

Comment: Thank you @Pandemonium for response ... I don't know  the error because of  console.error(error) statement or other thing, but i get " Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected input: null"  printed in my console when click on submit button